# Is this sonority hierarchy correct?

Tags: phonotactics

[image: first pass at defining the hierarchy]

I need to sort these phonemes properly before I get into clusters and making syllables, but I'm not sure I did it right.

Comment: Looks alright to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sonority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_hierarchy) refers to the amplitude of the sound signal; ie the louder a sound is, the higher it ranks. Vowels are loudest, as they are voiced and generally less constricted than most consonants. Within the vowels, the open ones (eg /a/),  are louder than the closed ones (/i/, /u/). Then laterals, nasals, fricatives, and finally plosives. Within each of these groups (where applicable) the voiced variant is higher than the voiceless one (eg /g/ > /k/, and /d/ > /t/).

This matches the ranking in your image, so I would say it is correct.